# Python: `__eq__()` doesn't work as expected when subclasses

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

First, a project that I am working using the plugin systme similar to [PEP-0478](https://peps.python.org/pep-0487/) using a [PriortyQueue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html) for insuring plugins run in the right order. I am going to leave out the how this works:

1. It is well documented in PEP-487
2. Not directly required for understanding this issue.

First, I have basic classes as below:

```py
# abstract.py
import abc

from dataclasses import data, field

@dataclass(order=True)
class PluginBase(abc.ABC):
    value: int

    def __eq__(self, __o: object) -> bool:
        print("PluginBase __eq__ called")
        return self.value == __o.value

# plugin_a.py
from abstract import PluginBase

class PluginA(PluginBase):
    pass

# plugin_b.py
from abstract import PluginBase

class PluginB(PluginBase):
    pass
```

First, after the plugins are discovered and loaded they are wrapped in a `dataclass` this is to ensure min amount of code for each plugin.

### Problem: `__eq__()` is never passed to subclasses.

It does not matter how I setup the classes or even use `funtools.total_ordering`.

One thing I noticed, is that if you do `assert PluginA(1) == PluginB(1)` always returns false and `assert PluginA(1) < PluginB(2)` always returns `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances` with the current classes.

This this always intended?

To fix the first issue, where `==` doesn't work you need to add:

```py
    def __eq__(self, __o: object) -> bool:
        print("Plugin __eq__ called")
        return super().__eq__(__o)
```

To one or both subclasses which addes more boiler plate code to the plugin system which I do not want.

To fix the '<' issue, you need to change `PluginBase` to:

```py
@functools.total_ordering
@dataclass
class PluginBase(abc.ABC):
    value: int

    def __eq__(self, __o: object) -> bool:
        print("PluginBase __eq__ called")
        return self.value == __o.value

    def __lt__(self, __o: object) -> bool:
        print("PluginBase __lt__ called")
        return self.value < __o.value
```

This allows you to do `PluginA(1) < PluginB(2)` which will be `true`. However, `==` still does not work here.

I think this is due to the differences in class instances and Python is enforcing `__eq__()` to check the instance type before anything else. Is there anyway to get this to work?

One solution is to wrap each of the Plugins into a comparable object and use that into the Queue.

Comment: It works for me, with three more lines to define the objects and compare then. Perhaps you could post a reproduction. (where it refers to ==)

Comment: 1) Your abstract base class has no abstract methods. 2) Your dataclass overwrites your explicit `__eq__` method because you didn't pass `eq=False` to the decorator. 3) Your `__eq__` method erroneously assumes that a value of type `object` will have a `value` attribute. If it doesn't, you should probably return `NotImplemented`.

Comment: Your question is extremely confusing because you included the \_\_eq\_\_ override in the code describing the problem, therefore that code actually works, so it's not easy to understand that you want it to work **without** it, using only the dataclass autogenerated comparator, which is what I understood and answered below

Comment: @KennyOstrom You can see from my posted answer where the `==` is. When I use the dataclass decorator, it seems to create a `eq()` function which checks the instance type of the object where PluginA is not PluginB so it fails even when they are extended from the same base class. At least that's my understanding from the Python docs + testing.

Comment: I was just tricked because your posted code didn't demonstrate the problem you wanted to ask about. And Jeekiii already posted the correct answer -- where'd that go?

Comment: as a side note, the use of `__` as prefix may lead to trouble - you may have read some not so good documentation that it makes a variable  "private" and that is "good practice". Inr ealitiy is not a feature that will help you much unless you know exactly what you are doing, and conclude you really need it. not the case here.

Answer (score 0):

@chepner was on the right track here.

Change code to here works:

```py
# abstract.py
import abc

from dataclasses import dataclass, field

@functools.total_ordering
@dataclass
class PluginBase(abc.ABC):
    value: int

    def __eq__(self, __o: object) -> bool:
        print("PluginBase __eq__ called")
        return self.value == __o.value

    def __lt__(self, __o: object) -> bool:
        print("PluginBase __lt__ called")
        return self.value < __o.value

# plugin_a.py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from abstract import PluginBase

@dataclass(eq=False)
class PluginA(PluginBase):
    pass

# plugin_b.py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from abstract import PluginBase

@dataclass(eq=False)
class PluginB(PluginBase):
    pass
```

Adding the `eq=False` forces it not to genereate the interclass `eq()` functions which then defaults to the base class.

```py
assert PluginA(1) < PluginB(2) # True
PluginBase __lt__ called
assert PluginA(1) == PluginB(1) # True
PluginBase __eq__ called
```

Some reason I just missed trying this combonation of options.

Comment: to be on the explicit side, you may want to add the argument `order=False` in the calls to `dataclass`  along `eq=False` .